# C# + .NET : Find the path of an app like chrome.exe in the computer (all disks, all directories)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, directory, subdirectory

the best that i have found about my problem is :

```
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "chrome.exe", new EnumerationOptions
{
    IgnoreInaccessible = true,
    RecurseSubdirectories = true
});
Console.WriteLine(filePaths);
```

But i dont know how to output to a string the appPath, it output this :

```
System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[System.String]
```

How can it output this : C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
And for any application instead of chrome...

Answer (score 1):

filePaths is a collection of multiple strings, so you'll need to iterate through it.

```
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
  Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

You can also consider functions like [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Ur the best ! 
I ll try this to find every path for my Launcher...

Comment: hummm Hi again... How can i use it for :

`
Process chrome = new Process();
chrome.StartInfo.FileName = $"THE PATH THAT WE FOUND";
chrome.Start();
`

Comment: Simply chrome.StartInfo.FileName = chromePath, where chromePath is a string

Comment: Btw you are a genius thx.
Yes Your right but the chrome path is founded with the foreach ...